# Why does bash expansion escape a string?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
user=wxlfrank
group="wxlfrank : wxlfrank sudo"
pattern="$user :*sudo*"
if [[ $group != "${user} :*sudo*" ]] ; then
    usermod -aG sudo $user
    echo "add user $user" 'into group sudo'
fi
```

Can anyone help to explain why the fifth line is expanded to

```
[[ wxlfrank : wxlfrank sudo != \w\x\l\f\r\a\n\k\ \:\*\s\u\d\o\* ]]
```

Comment: Because it's quoted?

Comment: Quotes don't create a string literal as in most languages; it's just shortcut for individually escaping each character within the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the quotes:

```
if [[ $group != ${user}\ :*sudo* ]] ; then
```

with quotes, the pattern is treated as literal string.

Note that, `[[` is a `bash` builtin (unlike `[` (`test`)), `bash` handles any expansion internally. So no word splitting (and pathname expansion *except* when `==`/`=`/`!=` is used) is done on the expansions.